# can anyone tell me why give an enter is necessary for return the prompt?

Tags: linux, process, parent-child

I have this code, the child process ends and the system prompt no return until I give an enter.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    pid_t id_hijo;
    int i;
    printf("1: el id del proceso main es %d\n", getpid());
    id_hijo = fork();
    printf("2: el id del proceso hijo es %d\n", id_hijo);
    if(id_hijo > 0){
        for (i = 0; i <=10; i++){
            printf("padre: %d\n", i);
        }
    }
    else{
        pid_t id_hijo2 = fork();
        if(id_hijo2 > 0){
            for (i = 10; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                printf("hijo 1: %d\n",i);
            }
            printf("getppid() hijo 1=%d\n",getppid());
        }
        else {
            for(i=10; i>=0; i--){
                printf("hijo 2: %d\n",i);
            }
            printf("getppid() hijo 2=%d\n",getppid());
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This isn't clear, because the function getppid() inside the child process don't need an "enter", or yes?

```
The output is: 

iMac-de-:Desktop be$ gcc programa3.c
iMac-de-:Desktop be$ ./a.out
1: el id del proceso main es 4466
2: el id del proceso hijo es 4467
padre: 0
padre: 1
padre: 2
padre: 3
padre: 4
padre: 5
padre: 6
padre: 7
padre: 8
padre: 9
padre: 10
2: el id del proceso hijo es 0
hijo 1: 10
hijo 1: 9
hijo 1: 8
hijo 1: 7
hijo 1: 6
hijo 1: 5
hijo 1: 4
hijo 1: 3
hijo 1: 2
hijo 1: 1
hijo 1: 0
getppid() hijo 1=1
iMac-de-Bertha:Desktop berhtvega$ hijo 2: 10
hijo 2: 9
hijo 2: 8
hijo 2: 7
hijo 2: 6
hijo 2: 5
hijo 2: 4
hijo 2: 3
hijo 2: 2
hijo 2: 1
hijo 2: 0
getppid() hijo 2=1
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely, you'll see that the prompt was printed already, after the `getppid() hijo 1=1` line.

The shell is only waiting for the parent process to exit, not the child process. When the parent exits, the shell displays the prompt. But the child process is still running, printing its `hijo 2` countdown. So these get printed after the prompt.

You can type another command at this time, you don't have to type <kbd>Enter</kbd> to get another prompt.

If you want all the child's output to happen before the prompt, you need to make the parent process call `wait()`, so it doesn't exit until the child is finished.